# Remove javascript attribute of onclick function?

Tags: html

How can you remove the onclick attribute of a javascript function (solved).

Comment: Without looking at your code, `_button[k].onclick = function() { return false; };` maybe? You have to assign a function to `.onclick`. `_button[k].onclick = return false` is just a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in the code,

1. the syntax error in assigning `_button[k].onclick = return false`, it should be wrapped in a function like `_button[k].onclick = function() {return false}` instead you can just delete the `onclick` property.
2. The wrong use of a [closure variable in a loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake), when the onclick handler is called `k` will be equal to `_button.length` so `_button[k]` will return undefined which will throw an error saying unable to access property `onclick` of undefined.

Try

```
for (var k = 0; k < _button.length; k++) {
    _button[k].onclick = function (e) {
        _counter++;

        if (_counter > _sArray.length - 1) {
            //here this refers to the button
            delete this.onclick;
            //the button and the element with said class are the same so you can use this.innerHTML to set the text
            this.innerHTML = 'Done';
        } else {
            update();
        };

        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

With **JQuery** the following would remove the `onclick` attribute from the button: `$("#buttonId").removeAttr("onclick")`, where `buttonId` is the `id` attribute of the button.